# Is it a bad practice for my project folder to also be an application in Django?

Tags: python, django, architecture

Say I have a Django project called `myproject`. Within this project there will of course be a folder called `myproject` which will house my settings file and other global configuration files. As my project grew and began to incorporate many different apps, I placed certain functionalities that were common to all of my apps in a `utils` module in my `myproject` folder. At this point, I want to write some unit tests for those utils, as well as add some global project commands that I feel it would make sense to house within the `myproject` folder. To have access to these functionalities, I need to add `myproject` to my list of installed apps. This works just fine, but I've never seen this done in a Django project.

My question is this : Is this a bad practice ? Are there unforeseen risks I'm not seeing here ? A cleaner way of doing things ? Would it be safer to create an app called `common` and have it house my utils, global commands etc. ? How do you usually organize your modules if they're defining project level functionalities ?

Basically my directory structure is simply the following :

```
.
├── myproject
│   ├── management
│   │   └── commands
│   └── utils
├── app1
├── app2
└── app3
```

And I'm wondering if I should add another app called `commonapp` where to house my common commands or if it's fine to add 'myproject' to my list of installed apps.

Comment: Can you add your directory tree of your project?

Comment: I've edited my question to include it.

Comment: For me, I usually made `common` or `core` app for those utils. It's more safe than making `myproject` app for avoiding ambiguous. But as you know, there's no right answer. You can choose your own way for your own reason.